# Where is the H+ ion in this step of glycolysis coming from?

Tags: biochemistry, cellular-respiration

[image: conversion of G3P to 1,3-bisphosphoglycerate]
(from Fundamentals of Biochemistry by Voet, 5th ed.)

In this step of glycolysis, I'm not seeing where the $\ce{H+}$ ion on the product side is coming from. It seems to me that the G3P's aldehydic H is replaced by phosphate, and that H is given to $\ce{NAD+}$ to make NADH. So where is the extra $\ce{H+}$ coming from?

Comment: Look at what you are substituting  OPO for

Comment: I've reverted the question to its original. Clearly the answer to the question needs to take into account the ambiguous nature of the equation, which does not make it clear whether it is meant to be a stoichiometric representation of the reaction occuring on the enzyme (which must involve discrete species) or adherence to a convention (which I assume, like Berg et al. is not explained) in which Pi is used to represent the fact that the reactive species (orthophosphate?) is in equilibrium with other phosphate species. Thanks @tomd for putting me right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although texts such as [Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22555/#A211) tend to refer to inorganic phosphate, $\ce{P_i}$,  as [orthophosphate ($\ce{PO4^{3-}}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acids_and_phosphates#Orthophosphate), the term inorganic phosphate is used because in aqueous solution at pH 7.6 several phosphate species exist, the predominant one being [$\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate). If this is regarded as $\ce{P_i}$, then *it* is the source of the $\ce{H^{+}}$, and the equation balances.

Note added by David:

On checking I find, in contrast to Berg, Lehninger’s book defines $\ce{P_i}$ as monohydrogen phosphate ($\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$), and [Fersht](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Mechanism-Protein-Science-Catalysis/dp/0716732688) actually writes the equation of the reaction (16-1) with $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$ rather than $\ce{P_i}$.

Comment: Ok, so do most sources assume $\ce{P_i}$ as being $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$ or as being $\ce{H2PO4^-}$? It seems like the source of my image assumes $\ce{P_i}$ is $\ce{HPO4^{2-}}$.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/ATP-hydrolysis .  It is about ATP hydrolysis which also releases Pi (the phosphate ion) but notice the resonance stabilisation. I think this is what anongoodnurse is meaning

Comment: This is very muddled. You are mixing up solubility and ionization, and if you want to discuss this you have to put the charges on.

Comment: @RickBeeloo No, the question is about the stoichiometry of the equation, it has nothing to do with resonance stabilization. In the link you cite the equation is balanced.

Comment: @David - I am not tech savvy enough to include both the superscript charge and the subscript. However, in truth, in cells, Pi does not exist as PO4-3. And ultimately, the H+ does, indeed, come from the solution, which has a number if weak acids and bases.

Comment: @tomd - I suppose it depends on exact definitions of inorganic phosphate. I'm glad you added your own answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the right answer, but what it seems to me you are arguing seems better expressed as follows. Orthophosphate (3–) may be counterbalanced by N+ or K+ in solution, but will be in equilibrium with a much greater amount of the monohydrogen acid (2–). If orthophosphate is removed an almost equivalent amount of this acid will dissociate regenerating the orthophosphate, but also a hydrogen ion. This hydrogen ion could be the one in the equation. If this is what you intend I can edit your answer with the charges shown.

Comment: @David - I agree with what you say. If you can write in mathematic (I can only write English), I would be happy and grateful for your improvement to my answer, however you want. Many thanks.

Comment: I've now edited your answer. Do modify or revert it if you are unhappy with any aspect of it.

Comment: @David - Thank you, it's good.I looked at how you wrote it. It's like reading nonsense words (I could never have done it.) Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I've added a short additional note and regard your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Although an answer that I have contributed an edit to has been, rightly, accepted, I decided to add my own answer to clarify a couple of points.

1. The equation in the question is what is known as a *biochemical* equation, *not* a *chemical* equation. As this [IUPAC document](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1994/pdf/6608x1641.pdf) notes:

> Chemical equations are written in terms of specific ionic and elemental species and balance elements and charge, whereas biochemical equations are written in terms of reactants that often consist of species in equilibrium with each other and do not balance elements that are assumed fixed, such as hydrogen at constant pH.

One should not, therefore, expect Voet’s equation to balance.

2. The [1974 paper of Buehner *et al.*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002228367490254X) on the crystallization of glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase includes the following (net reactants in yellow, hydrogens in orange):
   [image: GAPDH reaction]

…which answers the question.

It is interesting that the IUPAC document defines Pi as orthophosphate, although this is irrelevant to the question at hand as none of the old papers I have looked at use the abbreviation Pi.